# How can I get all the characters after a certain number of digits in a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, character

My question is fairly simple. I want to get all the characters in a string after a certain number of digits. For example, if I entered in 123 InsertIGN, I want to know how I can get all the characters after 123, no matter how many of them are there. I want it to still work if I entered 123 VeryLongWordHereshfusihdisa. I would want to get everything AFTER 123. Is there any way I can go about doing that? Sorry for the dumb question, I stopped coding in Java for a while and recently have come back. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: The simplest method would be `str.substring(str.indexOf("123") + 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your test case is "123" always in the first place of string. You can use substring as simple as

```
String testCase = "123ABCD!@#$";
String result = testCase.substring("123".length());
```

Or if your test case would be "123" is in random place, but still could get all the chars behind that. We can hack it to

```
String testCase = "ABCD123!@#$";
String splitBy

int index123 = testCase.indexOf("123") + "123".length();
String result = testCase.substring("123".length());
```

it will return

```
result = !@#$
```

Using `index123` object we are trying to get the position of the first "123" without "123" thats why we need to add length of "123".

Let's try using another test case

```
String testCase = "ABCD123!@#$123XYZ";
```

will return

```
result = !@#$123XYZ
```

Because we only process the first "123"

Comment: I remembered about .substring but forgot how to use it so I just didn't lol

Answer (score -1):

Get the Unicode code point integer assigned to each character in your input string.

```
String input = "123 InsertIGN" ;
List< Integer > codePoints = input.codePoints().boxed().toList() ;
```

Loop each code point. Ask if that character is a digit. If so, increment a count. Once your desired limit is reached, collect remaining characters.

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder() ;
int limit = 3 ;  // Number of digit occurrences to get past. 
int count = 0 ;
for( Integer codePoint : codePoints )
{
    if( count < limit )
    {
        if( Character.isDigit( codePoint ) ) { count ++ ; }
    }
    else
    {
        result.append( codePoint ) ;
    }
}
```

There are nifty ways to do that with streams. But as someone returning to Java programming, you may not be familiar with that. So the above is the old-school approach.